# How many routers does the average packet go through on the internet and what is their effect on internet speed?

Tags: router

For example, I'm on my laptop at my house sending packets between me and the stack exchange server (where ever that may be). How many routers are "between" me and the server? how much do these routers impact my internet speed. For example, if there were a direct cable between the two it would be faster than if there were 1000 routers between us.

I'm looking to get a sense of how many routers there are, where they are, who owns them and what impact they have on my connection speed.

Thanks

Comment: Google Traceroute

Comment: Try ping -R superuser.com

Comment: try [win+x] to get a command window then> tracert (or ping) superuser.com ... if you don't use IPV6

Comment: Your speed isn't affected it's the latency that would be. How many hops it takes for you to reach a given server depends on what kind of peerings your ISP and in turn his peers have. Your package might have to pass through several networks in order to reach its final destination.

Answer (score 0):

You could use traceroute and ping to study number of hops and end-to-end average latency from your IP address to a stackexchange server. This can be used to make correlations on number-of-hops and the internet speed.

But, it will not really translate to good causation analysis. This is because the 'speed' you see on your internet connection (even to a single server) is dependent on many factors.

A few points to get a broad view of what happens in the background.

1. There could be congestion on the network path between your IP and the server. This may cause packet loss and re-transmissions. It will also cause the internet protocols to slow-down (and avoid further congestion). Effect: increased latency; Perception: slow 'speed'.
   <sub>Most introductory articles and books on TCP/IP protocol and internetworking will give you details on these behaviors. Also see this ServerFault question: [How much network latency is “typical” for east - west coast USA?](https://serverfault.com/q/137348/4721)</sub>
2. Change in routes (this happens less often) triggers a new route search. Communication between the end-points at this time slows down (packet loss and re-transmissions).
   <sub>One paper to browse on the subject -- [Understanding Network Delay Changes Caused by Routing Events](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~zmao/Papers/sigm07_routechange.pdf).</sub>
3. The 'server' you are measuring against may be hosted from multiple points in the Internet. This makes repeated measurements difficult. But, it actually helps you get better 'speed' to the server because the internet protocols work continuously towards that. <sub>You might see this as a change in the IP address of the server (in your ping/traceroute tests) at different times of the day or across days.</sub>
4. While the maximum hop count that your packets will see is not likely to ever approach the 1000 number it is important to note that [not all devices that the packet will cross through on the way will be counted in this hop-count](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/5008/8248). This again confuses any correlation you might try with lot's of hop and latency measurements.

These things will confuse your long-term analysis based on hop-count and impact on internet speed. So, while [the correlation is a fun exercise](http://cs-www.bu.edu/faculty/crovella/paper-archive/hpcs95/paper.html), do not make the mistake of interpreting correlation as causation.